# unable to fill the from using selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am new to python and i was trying fill the form using python (selenium)

There are few fields in form , i can able fill few ! but there is one field called tag ! unable to fill

Here is my code

```
from multiprocessing import Value
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.common.actions

#open a website to create profile 
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://socialbookmarking.agency/") 
sleep(1)

#open login popup
link = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, 'Sign in')
link.click()
sleep(1)

#login to website 
email = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username_or_email")
email.send_keys("test@test.com")
sleep(1)
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password")
password.send_keys("testpassword")
sleep(1)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"][1]').click()
sleep(2)


#prepare form submission  

driver.get("https://socialbookmarking.agency/submit-listing/details/")
title = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "title")
location = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "location")
website_url = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "website_url")
country = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "country")
small_description = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "small_description")
description = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "description")
newtag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'bootstrap-tagsinput has-focus')]") 


#fill the form
title.send_keys("Our First Test post")
sleep(1)
location.send_keys("Melbourne")
sleep(1)
website_url.send_keys("www.firstpost.com")
sleep(1)
country.send_keys("Australia")
sleep(1)
small_description.send_keys("This is the few line of test small description")
sleep(1)
description.send_keys("This is the few line of test description, you can add more content here! not sure about limit ")
sleep(1)
#ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element(newtag, 'test').perform()
newtag.send_keys("test")
sleep(1)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@type="submit"][1]').click()

sleep(2)
```

There are 2 input fields for one value

[image]

Inside the text field, there is Another field!

[image]

How to fill the data for this field!

Comment: Hope you didn't expose your password. If you did, I advise you to change the password from your account ASAP.

Comment: Regarding the question, looks like you're selecting the div and not the input field inside. You need to select the input field by it's name `newtag[post_tag]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is in the below line:

```
newtag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'bootstrap-tagsinput has-focus')]")
```

The node you should be locating and sending text to should be `input` not `div`.

Change it as below:

```
newtag = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'bootstrap-tagsinput')]//input")
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line to

```
newtag = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'bootstrap-tagsinput has-focus')]")
```

this

```
newtag = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.bootstrap-tagsinput > input[type="text"][data-form-type="other"]')
```